# How to make a bot to navigate a site?

Tags: php, automation, bots

Given a product id, associates have to navigate a vendors website, log in, perform a search, in order to get details on a product for a customer.

My employers want a program that can use the product id, and navigate the vendors website, and perform the search and everything to get the information thus saving the associate from having to manually repeat this task every time a customer wants more information about a product.

I know many sites use methods to prevent (CAPTCHA) exactly what I am trying to do. So I do not know if that automatically makes my given project an "evil" one. But I certainly do not have evil intentions, my employers simply want to save associates time on getting information that they are going to get regardless. However, if this is "evil" please explain why, so I can explain to my employers why we should not go down this road. That being said...

How can I make something like this in PHP?

Comment: `So I do not know if that automatically makes my given project an "evil" one.` - I think that depends entirely on the target site's terms of use. If they have none, I guess on the legal side, some default applies. For most jurisdictions, that is *probably* "it's fine" or a grey area - but only a lawyer can answer that properly. But why not ask the people running the site for permission? If they agree, that would be the nicest solution.

Comment: I think I heard that Darth Vader was working on a similar project and, after all, he's pretty evil.

Comment: It's not necessarily evil.  However, if they have a robots.txt in their site, honor it as best you can.  And you shouldn't peg the site and blast it with requests.  That's a good way to get your application blocked from the site.

Comment: That's evil for sure. Try to register for some google service and consider captcha image you have to enter. It's complicity is direct consequence of such roboting. A vendor, who is willing to give information away, have an API for that for sure. While such a scraping makes people defend against that, and it makes life of humans harder. That's evil at it's best: one greedy robot-maker makes troubles for thousands.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what site you are trying to access. Many sites have an API that can be used to access data. If that's not the case, you may need to write a program that loads the html using a GET request, parses through the response, and retrieves the information you want. Without more details, that's the best answer I can give.

Answer (score 1):

To start with I'd recommend reading up on cURL and DOM

cURL: http://php.net/curl (for fetching pages, even simulating search form)

DOM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php (to parse the fetched pages)